# What is deterministic validation for hardware wallets?

Tags: hardware-wallet, ledger-hardware-wallet

On bitcoin.com, they mention that the Ledger Nano hardware wallet "while not open-source, .. can be deterministically validated."

https://www.bitcoin.com/choose-your-wallet/ledgernano

What does this mean? What kind of validation can be performed? Does this have anything to do with the yellow "Centralized verification" label they have for it?